# 2 (or more) button views for the same onClick method

Tags: java, android, view, onclick

I'm a novice android developper and was wondering:

Could I have 2 buttons to be linked into the same, 1 onClick method (which i'll presumably override to accept 2 extra parameter, int btnId  and View targetTextView for instance) in order to decide which button is calling the method  and then which TextView text to update?

For Example:
btn1 will update the text on text_view_1
and btn2 will update text_view_2.

Except they we will  be linked to the same method:

```
public void generalOnClick(View view, String btnId, String textViewId){...}
```

Comment: Your question is bit complicated to understand, can you explain properly?

Comment: In your View.OnClickListener, you will have a View v params, just compare the v.getId() with the two R.ids

Comment: @Apurva I've edited my question, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"
    android:onClick="btnClick"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Two"
    android:onClick="btnClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Button Click Function in your Activity**

```
public void btnClick(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)view;
    int id = tv.getId();
    if(id==R.id.one) {
        tv.setText("One Clicked");
    } else if(id==R.id.two){
        tv.setText("Two Clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set an tag to button and verify it with onClick method that which buttons click event has been triggered , if it doesn't work then follows following trick,

define an common method for the functionality which you are going to execute on button click, make it as common function.

define independent onclick event for both button and then while calling the common function which created above pass some unique param and verify it.

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.getId().Equals(btn1.getId())){
                //do your work here
            }
            else{
                //work for 2nd button
            }
        };

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
```